Is Armadillo C++ library memory management "shallow copy" or "deep copy"?
I ran the following code and found that the memory addresses of the two matrices are different. Does this mean that Armadillo matrices use "deep copy" when performing operations like equal sign value assignment or parameter passing?
arma::mat A = arma::zeros<arma::mat>(2, 2);
arma::mat B = A;    
auto pa = A.memptr();
auto pb = B.memptr();

I got:
pa: 0x00000024b74ff740
pb: 0x00000024b74ff7f0
